# Class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6.0.1

I started working on app development tutorials from today and already started facing hard to deal bug. I know it may be easy for pro developers, but not for me.

The simple app I made is - To Do List

Under new project -> Tabbed Application - > Swift -> iPhone
This is the code for second view controller,

```
    import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
var toDoItems:[String] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var toDoItem: UITextField!

    @IBAction func addItem(sender: AnyObject) {

        toDoItems.append(toDoItem.text)

        println(toDoItems)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

I am sick of this SIGABRT problem. Other people are using the exact same code that I am and there program is working perfectly fine. Not sure why I am having this issue.

I tried the following:

- Clear the cache
- Restarted the Xcode multiples times
- Redid the complete code again saving as a completely different file

I am using the following:

- xcode 6.0.1 (6A317)
- OS Yosemite
- I have a developer account

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact error and I know it is frustrating, but it is absolutely dumb. 
The problem is with an outlet. Maybe you deleted the line of code and/or replaced it, but the link still exists.

In your main.storyboard check all the outlets, control+(click on outlet) and check if it is linked to something.
Once you correct that it should run with no problems.